# How to Create Local Directory in Blazor Webassembly

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

I am running a Blazor webassembly app without sending any files to the server - only fetching the app from the server.

How can I let the user of my app create a folder on their local machine using C#?

I have tested this but nothing happens. The method should create a folder when user presses a button like this:  `<button @onclick="@(()=>TestDir())">Press</button>`

```
@using System.IO

    void TestDir()
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\TestDir");
    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/KristofferStrube/Blazor.FileSystemAccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll not be able to do this.

All activity inside the Browser's WebAssembly (including Blazor) is 'sand-boxed' to prevent access to local files.  This is by design to ensure security.

It wouldn't be a desirable situation for any page that you visit to start creating / deleting / updating directories and files on your machine.